# complete square of summation of odd numbers

Tags: number-theory

Suppose we have an integer(which may be odd or even), let us say for example $x=20$, also we have an odd number which is also known (let us say for example $y=39$).
Is there any formula that tell us how many consecutive odd numbers starting from $y$ that if we add them together with $x$, then we have a result of perfect square.
In our case, our perfect square will be : $perfect=100$, and it is $perfect=20+39+41$.
so the answer will be $2$ odd numbers (include the starting one).
any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Ross Millikan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1827/ross-millikan)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3527809/602049) states, you're looking for an $n \ge 1$ such that, for some integer $a$, you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
n(y+n-1)+x & = a^2 \\
n^2 + (y - 1)n + x & = a^2 \\
n^2 + (y - 1)n + x - a^2 & = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This is a quadratic equation in $n$. To get positive integral values for $n$ requires, at a minimum, the discriminant is a perfect square, say of $b$. This gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(y-1)^2 - 4(x - a^2) & = b^2 \\
(y-1)^2 - 4x + 4a^2 & = b^2 \\
(y-1)^2 - 4x & = b^2 - (2a)^2 \\
(y-1)^2 - 4x & = (b - 2a)(b + 2a)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Call the left hand side value $c$, i.e.,

$$c = (y-1)^2 - 4x \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Thus, you have for factors $f_1$ and $f_2$ of $c$ that

$$b - 2a = f_1 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

$$b + 2a = f_2 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

where $f_1 f_2 = c$. Solving these equations gives that \eqref{eq5A} minus \eqref{eq4A} has $4a = f_2 - f_1 \implies a = \frac{f_2 - f_1}{4}$. Also, adding the equations gives $2b = f_1 + f_2 \implies b = \frac{f_1 + f_2}{2}$. In particular, this shows that $f_2 - f_1$ must be a multiple of $4$, so you only need to check those factors.

The full quadratic formula equation for $n$ from \eqref{eq1A}, and using \eqref{eq2A}, is

$$n = \frac{1 - y \pm |b|}{2} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Since you are looking for positive solutions, you want to use only $n = \frac{1 - y + |b|}{2}$, and just the smallest one which is positive. Thus, you want to have the least value of $|b|$ which is greater than $y - 1$ and with the same parity.

This technique is most useful when $c$ in \eqref{eq3A} is relatively small, but with $y$ and $x$ potentially being quite large, since factoring can be a quite expensive operation for large values. For cases where $c$ is quite large, I don't know if there is any other way easier than perhaps just checking the next values until you get a perfect square.

Comment: Nice! I am working on the RSA factorization problem, actually I have done a proof that if we have an effective way (without a lot of trials) for doing what I asked about, then we solved the RSA factorization problem, if you could look for a way to do what you did with very large y and x, then we can share the research and many other things, thank you for your effort

Comment: @Yaser You're welcome for my effort. However, keep in mind the limitations of this result. In particular, as I stated, unless the value of $c$ in my ($3$) is relatively small, this technique will generally not work very well. With the sizes of values involved in standard RSA calculations, I suspect this method will usually not work well. Also, I doubt there's any method which provides a relatively simple and, more importantly, fast method to solve your problem with any arbitrary very large values of $x$ & $y$. Nonetheless, you never know what you may discover, so it's worth continuing to try.

Comment: Thank you again, what makes me working on this problem is that I do not believe in randomness, there should be a rule that conducting what happens, and I am looking not only for rules, but also for patterns, so I will continue trying

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but too much for a comment:
The sum of all the odd numbers below $y$ is $\left(\frac{y-1}2\right)^2$.  If you add $n$ odd numbers starting with $y$ the greatest is $y+2n-2$ and the sum of all the odd numbers up to that is $\left(\frac{y+2n-1}2\right)^2$.  You are then looking for
$$\left(\frac{y+2n-1}2\right)^2-\left(\frac{y-1}2\right)^2+x=n(y+n-1)+x$$
to be a perfect square.  I don't have any good ideas for that in the general case.

Comment: you mean : n(y + n-1)+x , as the final answer, I really derived the same formula, but I am asking about the final answer, how we can know where a quadratic equation hits a perfect square?

Comment: Also  would like to say thank you very much

Comment: @Yaser:  If you had derived it, you should have put it in the question so people knew where to start from.  I found the error and corrected it.

Comment: I am sorry for not mentioning this, and I will do that the next time, thank you again.